# Animated short film about a "surrealism salesman"

Tags: story-identification, animation, short-film

I'm looking for the name of (and a link to) a 3D short film I saw about 8 years ago or so. I got the impression it was an animation student project or somesuch, but I had come across it so it must have been shown publicly somewhere.

It was a sort of urban fantasy thing about a "surrealism salesman" knocking on the door of an apartment. A young woman, who is an anthropomorphic fox, answers the door. The salesman explains his trade - he sells surrealism in any amount anyone is willing to pay for. Wary but with piqued interest, the woman buys one dollar's worth of surrealism, for which the salesman recites:

> The green cat is softly *mooing*!

The woman is somewhat underwhelmed, and says so. The salesman replies that she had only bought one dollar's worth, and that one gets what one pays for. The woman then asks for a larger amount's worth (I believe ten dollars). The salesman accepts, then very surrealistically disappears from existence, along with the hallways behind him (imagine the entire shot, background and character, swirling down a drain, leaving the screen black). Cut to the woman, astonished, leaning out of her apartment door to look into the hall, exclaiming:

> Thank you very much!

Unfortunately I don't remember where I saw this short, but the line about the green cat has always stuck with me, and I wouldn't mind finding it again.

Here are some additional details I can remember:

- Short film was animated in 3D, roughly 5 minutes long
- Set in a city; I vaguely recall a brown brick apartment building as the only exterior shot.
- Both of the main characters were anthropomorphic animals.

  - The customer was a female fox wearing shorts and a tank top
  - I don't remember what species the salesman was, but he was wearing a classic door-to-door salesman's outfit (brown suit, fedora, etc).
- The animation itself was quite good - nothing amazing by today's standards, but the character models and animation (the foci of the short) were well-done. The walls and a lot of background textures were a bit flat and simplistic.